# In Skype bot framework some controls does not work on mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, skype, botframework, skypedeveloper

We are integrating a [Skype Bot](https://dev.botframework.com/) for one of our applications.

Some don't work well on mobile and windows platforms.

**1) [Hero Card](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.herocard)**

In the the button events don't fire when clicking.

Here is how I do the implementation,

```
CardAction cardAction = new CardAction()
{
    Value = $"{item.DocumentUrl.ToString()}",
    Type = "openUrl",
    Title = "View Document"
};

cardActionList = new List<CardAction>();
cardActionList.Add(cardAction);

HeroCard heroCard = new HeroCard()
{
    Title = $"Sample Document",
    Subtitle = $"Library : {SerchResult.LibraryName}",
    Images = cardImageList,
    Buttons = cardActionList
};
```

**2) [SigninCard](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dc/d03/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_signin_card.html)**

In android devices and windows skype app this control don't work but in iphones do.

Here is how I do the implementation,

```
CardAction plsButton = new CardAction()
{
    Value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"] + "?id=" + message.From.Id,
    Type = "signin",
    Title = "Login"//,
    //Image = "http://www.enadoc.com/img/assets/logo.png"
};

sbuttons.Add(plsButton);

SigninCard signinCard = new SigninCard()
{
    Buttons = sbuttons
};
```

Are these current limitations of the platforms or am I making a mistake in the implementation?

Comment: what is the value of `{item.DocumentUrl.ToString()}`? Is it valid url? actually, you can use `ActionTypes.OpenUrl` and `ActionTypes.Signin` instead of 'openUrl' and 'signin' to avoid typo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the issue you are seeing in Skype, is due to the scheme of the URL. For Skype, it must be https.